# FFTPACK Scipy global name is not defined correctly. How to fix?

Tags: opencv, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library

```
import scipy
from scipy import*
from scipy.fftpack import*
from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft, fft2


def fouriertransform(self):     #function for Fourier transform computation
    for filename in glob.iglob ('*.tif'):
      imgfourier = scipy.misc.imread(filename) #read the image
      arrayfourier = numpy.array([imgfourier])#make an array 
    # Take the fourier transform of the image.
      fone = fftpack.fft(arrayfourier)
    # Now shift so that low spatial frequencies are in the center.
      ftwo = fftpack.fftshift(fone)
    # the 2D power spectrum is:
      psd2D = np.abs(ftwo)**2
      L = psd2D
      np.set_printoptions(threshold=3)
    #np.set_printoptions(precision = 3, threshold = None, edgeitems = None, linewidth = 3, suppress = True, nanstr = None, infstr = None, formatter = None)
    for subarray in L:
        for array in subarray:
            for array in subarray:
                for elem in array:
                    print '%3.10f\n' % elem
```

I receive global name fftpack is not defined. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

None of your import variations put the name `fftpack` into your module's namespace.  This does:

```
from scipy import fftpack
```